# How to monitor number of times the application was used?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I need to include a tracking service in an package manager app I am writing. It needs to track number of times downloaded and duration of use for the downloaded apps. Any ideas or suggestions for how I can approach this?

Comment: You could probably call server/service periodically, and store number of app loads during a phone "session" (boot -> present momen). You will also have to identify different devices while processing service calls. (though I'm new to android)

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? You might want to look at [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/).

Comment: But I need to monitor some aplications that have been downloaded. I'm not sure that Google Analytics can help me there.

Comment: Can you not just put the analytics tracking code in each of these applications? It seems pretty open-ended.

Comment: But the problem is, that I have to make App Downloader, and track usage of downloaded applications, so I don't have acces to modify code.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from your question. For that, you'd have to write your own tracking service unless you can piggyback on Analytics by submitting your own data.